# Get the width and height in Jetpack Compose View

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I try to get the width and height in Jetpack Compose View. I use the below method

```
fun Greeting() {
    val configuration = LocalConfiguration.current
    val width = configuration.screenWidthDp.dp
    Column {

        Canvas(modifier = Modifier
            .padding(16.dp)
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .height(200.dp)
            .background(Color.Yellow)) {
            drawPath(Path().apply {
                lineTo((width.toPx() - 32.dp.toPx()), 200.dp.toPx())
            }, Color.Black, style = Stroke(2.dp.value))
        }
    }
}
```

Notice I have to explicitly `(width.toPx() - 32.dp.toPx()` to draw the line to the end of my Canvas, as I have to manually subtract the padding on both ends.

Is there a way I can get the width of the Compose Canvas view, without manually subtracting the `32.dp` padding?

Answer (score 0):

you can get your composable width and height simply using `Modifier.onGloballyPositioned`
here is the sample:

```
var size by remember { mutableStateOf(IntSize.Zero) }

SomeComposable(
  modifier = Modifier.width().height()
      .onGloballyPositioned {
          size = it.size
      }
```

and you can change the size to `Dp` with this method

```
@Composable
fun Int.pxToDp() = with(LocalDensity.current) { 
    this@pxToDp.toDp() 
}
```

use this method like this:

```
Modifier.width(pxValue.pxToDp())
```

Comment: Thanks. This returns in Pixel I guess. Is it possible to get back in Dp value?

Answer (score 0):

`Canvas`, actually `DrawScope`, or Modifier.pointerInput(), this is very helpful for getting touch dimensions, returns the size of  via `size` param. and `drawScope` extends `Density` which you can convert size in pixel in Int to dp using toDp() if required.

```
Canvas(
    modifier = Modifier
        .padding(16.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(200.dp)
){
    val size: Size = this.size
    val width: Float = size.width
    val height: Float = size.height
    val widthDp = width.toDp()

}
```

DrawScope source code

```
@DrawScopeMarker
@JvmDefaultWithCompatibility
interface DrawScope : Density {

    /**
     * The current [DrawContext] that contains the dependencies
     * needed to create the drawing environment
     */
    val drawContext: DrawContext

    /**
     * Center of the current bounds of the drawing environment
     */
    val center: Offset
        get() = drawContext.size.center

    /**
     * Provides the dimensions of the current drawing environment
     */
    val size: Size
        get() = drawContext.size

    /**
     * The layout direction of the layout being drawn in.
     */
    val layoutDirection: LayoutDirection

  // rest of DrawScope functions
}
```

Comment: If you don't assign a size Modifier drawScope returns 0 width and 0 height but it doesn't prevent drawing anything, let's say  a circle with radius 100f unless you clip via clip, clipToBounds or graphicsLayer